# things need more time to be worked/to work on/working on

Tags: meaning

> 1 Some things need more time to be worked on.
>
> 2 Some things need more time to work on.
>
> 3 Some things need more time working on.

It seems to me that all three mean the same, is it so?

Comment: #2 and #3 are syntactically invalid. Such usages do occur in relaxed conversational contexts, but there's a "dangling participle" error. The initial  subject is "things", but they can't be the unspecified subject that need to "work on" *themselves*. You should use an explicitly passive construction as in #1 to avoid this "error".

Comment: OK. But "This car needs repairing" is valid, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe "invalid" above was a bit strong. As [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=needs+repairing%2Cneeds+to+be+repaired&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) shows, usage has shifted pretty decisively from ***needs repairing*** to ***needs to be repaired*** (for a construction syntactically identical to your example #3 above). Use it if you like, but just be aware you're in an ever-decreasing minority. Note that this shift is far less marked in *British* English, so as a Brit myself I don't make much of a distinction. But Americans may get "picky".